# Contact List, adding through "Connect to Outlook" but only first, last name and email is populatign

Tags: list, outlook

I need to be able to populate job title, business phone, mobile phone, email, ect, when adding a new contact to contact list (Active Manager's contact list) when adding from outlook. What's happening?

Comment: Pls specify your sharepoint and outlook version

Comment: SP 2010. Outlook 2010